# Bootstrap Carousel not sliding from one picture to the next

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The carousel will not slide from one picture to the next.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1.0" />
<title>Economic Prosperity - The No.1 Minecraft Economy Server!</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>

.carousel .item {
    width: 100%; /*slider width*/
    max-height: 400px; /*slider height*/
}
.carousel .item img {
    width: 100%; /*img width*/
}
/*full width container*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .block {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class=" navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="#" class="brand">Economic Prosperity</a>

                        <ul class="nav pull-left">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Server Status:</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" style="color:#00CC00"><b>Online</b></a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="nav pull-right">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary">Log In</a>
                        </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container" style="width:100%;"> <!--Start of Carousel -->
        <section class="block">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">



            <div class="active item">
                <img src="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/299/f/6/minecraft_cave_by_harryisland-d31jtwd.jpg" alt="Slide1" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2013/066/6/d/minecraft_grass_background_by_lastvoltage-d5x9vzb.png" alt="Slide2" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/4206/tapeta16x9.png" alt="Slide3" />
            </div><div class="carousel-caption" >
            <h1 style="color:#999">EcoPro - The No.1 Server dedicated to Economy!</h1>
            <p class="lead">Sell your items, trade with players, sell on the auction and even set up your own shop in a city!</p>

        </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
</section>    
    </div> <!--End of Carousel -->

    <div class="hero-unit" style="width:90%; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;"> <!-- Start Hero -->
    <h2>What is EcoPro all about?</h2>
    <p>We aim to provide the best server out there with the sole main aim of gaining wealth to purchase benefits. Our server is not just your standard server, we put effort, time and skill into the creation of it. The sole aim of this server is to entertain YOU as best it can. The server is 100% non profit, so all of the donations recieved go straight back into the server to add to the quality of your gaming experience!
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Tell me more!</a></p>
    </div> <!-- End Hero Unit -->

    <div class="container" style="width:400px; float:left; margin-left:2%"> <!-- Server Features -->

    <div class="well">

        <h3>The Server's main Features:</h3>
        <p>
        <li>Economy (Duh!)</li>
        <li>Custom World</li>
        <li>Cities</li>
        <li>Wealth based ranks</li>
        <li>McMMo + Spells + Shops + More!</li>
        </p>

    </div>
    </div> <!-- End server features -->

    <div class="container">

    <img src="" width="140px" height="140px" class="img-circle" />

    </div>


<script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Load this when the DOM is ready
$(function(){
  // You used .myCarousel here. 
  // That's the class selector not the id selector,
  // which is #myCarousel
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need only for the buttons to work, I have looked at this for ages and cannot figure out what is wrong. I have also looked at other answers and they have not helped.

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but it looks like you have jquery loaded twice, once from bootstrap and once directly from the jquery site.  That can cause problems.  Also, are you getting an error message in the javascript console?

Comment: Are you looking for it to slide automatically? And does it do anything when you click on the arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had included two `jQuery` files, you need to remove one.

Also you need to put the `div` with a class `carousel-caption` within the `div` which contains the `items`, although I am not sure about that.

As long as you don't want the slider to move on its own, you can also remove the javascript at the bottom of the page as well.

With this changes, the slider seems to be working, you can look at the code at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/exiyew/1/edit), also look at the [full screen demo](http://jsbin.com/exiyew/1)

Comment: it works! Apart from you have to manually click across before they start to auto scroll (and only the last 2 scroll)?

Comment: look at this [one](http://jsbin.com/exiyew/2), I accidentally deleted the javascript to set interval.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem where my carousel would only load the first image and would not slide. It turned out that while moving code around I put the bootstrap.min.js script tag above the jquery script tag. When I moved the jquery tag up to load before bootstrap, it started working again.

Did not work:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Did work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm also having the same problem and I eliminate the issue by simply removing the bootstrap 4 
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">, 

which on top of another bootstrap 5 min js.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear as to what your exact issue is. But here is a fiddle which I started with your code.

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/NzZTW/1/

To make bootstrap slide automatically you have to set and interval.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
});
```

**Note:**  The animation doesn't seem to be present, as to why this is I am not 100% certain. What I do know is that the animation on the bootstrap carousel is handled via CSS3 transitions. So its possibly a browser issue. However this appears to work as expected (*for the most part*).

Comment: Ill give it a go, I did not originally have the duped jquery, i was trying it locally. The buttons don't work.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle? Or provide a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. This worked for me.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
                $('.carousel').carousel('next');
             }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Bootstrap (v3) Carousel worked fine apart from the slide animation. Then realised I was loading in the script for Owl Carousel from a previous (abandoned) page experiment. As soon as I removed the Owl Carousel script, the Bootstrap Carousel sliding animation started to work perfectly.